# Changing libvirt emulator: Permission denied

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt, virt-manager

I'm trying to use a binary of Qemu that I compiled using [this](https://at.projects.genivi.org/wiki/display/GDP/QEMU+with+hardware+graphics+acceleration) tutorial, since the version of Qemu that's packaged with my OS, Debian, doesn't seem to support OpenGL acceleration with Spice. After a successful compilation, I tried to set the <emulator> tag to the path to new Qemu executable in /usr/local/bin, but I receive the following error:

`error: internal error: Failed to probe QEMU binary with QMP: libvirt:  error : cannot execute binary /usr/local/bin/qemu-2.12.1/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64: Permission denied`

The 'emulator' part of my virsh edit configuration file is as follows:

`<emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>`

I have experimented with changing the permissions and ownership of the file, made sure to allow execution (`chmod a+x`), however none seem to work.

If there are any other ways of using the OpenGL acceleration feature of Qemu, please let me know.

I am currently using Debian Stretch, with the the virt-manager, libvirt-daemon and qemu-kvm from the 'testing' repository, on an Intel Core i5-8400, using the integrated GPU. I have compiled Qemu so I could use the OpenGL 3D acceleration feature with 'libvirglrenderer'.

Comment: Just to verify, no SELinux is running? Or if it is, the context is set correctly on the file? The directory where the file is locatedis also set to allow traversal, yes?

Comment: You need to check the permissions of the file _and all of its containing directories_. You may find `namei -l <file>` useful for this.

Comment: @roaima It's Linux-specific. I'm not aware of any other Unix that has anything like it.

Comment: @KevinO I’m using Debian, so SELinux is not available. As far as I know, AppArmor is not restricting anything.

Comment: @Michael Hampton I have already set the permissions to execute and tried setting the owner to root.

Comment: @wispi Please see my previous comment.

Comment: @MichaelHampton which comment are you referring to?

Comment: I said: "You need to check the permissions of the file and all of its containing directories. You may find `namei -l <file>` useful for this." You do not appear to have acted on this. If you have, then please edit your question and add its output.

Comment: The output of namei -l [path to Qemu executable] is: `f: /usr/local/bin/qemu-2.12.1/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64
drwxr-xr-x root root  /
drwxr-xr-x root root  usr
drwxrwsr-x root staff local
drwxr-sr-x root staff bin
drwxr-sr-x root staff qemu-2.12.1
drwxr-sr-x root staff x86_64-softmmu
-rwxr-xr-x root staff qemu-system-x86_64
`. I can still run the file by entering the path in terminal.

Comment: I am having the same issue after installing qemu 3.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just solved same problem on Debian Buster. Apparmor was denying access to my compiled qemu binary.
You can check if apparmor is enabled on your system using command:

```
sudo aa-status
```

If your output contains following lines then apparmor is surely enabled and needs to be configured to allow access to your compiled binary:

```
...
22 profiles are in enforce mode.
...
   /usr/sbin/libvirtd
...
3 processes are in enforce mode.
   /usr/sbin/libvirtd (1098)
...
```

Add apparmor permission for libvirt to execute your qemu binary. You can do it, for example, with placing following lines in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.libvirtd` just before last `'}'` symbol in config. End of config would look then like this:

```
# ... skipped lines
  /usr/bin/kvm rmix,
  /usr/local/bin/qemu-2.12.1/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 rmix,
}
```

Probably you will also need to add same apparmor permissions for qemu in `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu`:

```
  /usr/bin/kvm rmix,
  /usr/local/bin/qemu-2.12.1/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 rmix,
```

You can reload apparmor rulesets using `sudo systemctl reload apparmor`.
Apparmor rules syntax described, for example, [here](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/security/html/book.security/cha.apparmor.profiles.html).

Comment: It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

@alexcloud2 is the best answer.  I had to modify the apparmor config line a little (probably due to recent software changes.)  In `usr.sbin.libvirtd` I added the line:

```
/usr/local/bin/* PUx,
```

Answer (score 0):

I run across this issues in fedora, when I am trying to run a self-built qemu, then I just disable selinux, it works.
FYI https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/changing-selinux-states-and-modes/#selinux-disabling-selinux